# How to Get Multiple 'Keys' For a Command

Tags: python, command

How do I set multiple inputs for a command:

```
while True:
    option = input('What Units Are You Using? (Q to Quit) ').lower()
    if option == ['millimeters' , 'mm']:
        a = int(input('Enter Your number: '))
        while True:
            b = a / 10 # centimeters 
            c = a / 1000 # meters  
            print('Okay- Heres what we got:', b,'centimeters(cm) and', c,' meters (m)')
            break
```

So for: if option == ['millimeters' , 'mm']:   How do I get it to run both millimeters and mm?
(Python 3.33)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` operator (which checks the member existence), like this

```
if option in ['millimeters' , 'mm']:
```

Now, the `if` condition will be satisfied if `option` is either `millimeters` or `mm`.

**Suggestions:**

1. You don't need an infinite loop here.
2. You can use `format` method to compose strings.

So, your improved program looks like this

```
while True:
    option = input('What Units Are You Using? (Q to Quit) ').lower()
    if option in ['millimeters' , 'mm']:
        a = int(input('Enter Your number: '))
        b, c = a / 10, a / 1000
        print('Okay- Heres what we got: {} centimeters(cm) and {} meters (m)'.format(b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    option = input('What Units Are You Using? (Q to Quit) ').lower()

    if option == 'millimeters' or  option == 'mm':

        a = int(input('Enter Your number: '))

        while True:


            b = a / 10 # centimeters 

            c = a / 1000 # meters

            print('Okay- Heres what we got:', b,'centimeters(cm) and', c,' meters (m)')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extended version:

```
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input     # Python 2.x
else:
    inp = input         # Python 3.x

class Unit:
    def __init__(self, short_singular, short_plural, long_singular, long_plural, per_meter):
        self.ss = short_singular
        self.sp = short_plural
        self.ls = long_singular
        self.lp = long_plural
        self.per_meter = per_meter
        self.names = {short_singular, short_plural, long_singular, long_plural}

    def match(self, name):
        return name in self.names

    def to_meters(self, amt):
        return amt / self.per_meter

    def from_meters(self, amt):
        return amt * self.per_meter

    def to_str(self, amt, sig=3, short=False):
        if amt == 1.0:
            s = self.ss if short else self.ls
        else:
            s = self.sp if short else self.lp
        return "{{:0.{}f}} {{}}".format(sig).format(amt, s)

units = [
    Unit('in', 'ins', 'inch',       'inches',    39.3701),
    Unit('ft', 'ft',  'foot',       'feet',      3.28084),
    Unit('yd', 'yds', 'yard',       'yards',     1.09361),
    Unit('mi', 'mi',  'mile',       'miles', 0.000621371),
    Unit('mm', 'mm',  'millimeter', 'millimeters', 1000.),
    Unit('cm', 'cm',  'centimeter', 'centimeters',  100.),
    Unit('m',  'm',   'meter',      'meters',         1.),
    Unit('km', 'km',  'kilometer',  'kilometers',  0.001)
]

def get_unit(prompt):
    while True:
        name = inp(prompt).strip().lower()
        for unit in units:
            if unit.match(name):
                return unit
        print("I don't know that one.")

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    a   = get_unit("Convert from what unit? ")
    b   = get_unit("To what unit? ")
    amt = get_float("How many {}? ".format(a.lp))
    res = b.from_meters(a.to_meters(amt))
    print("The result is {}.".format(b.to_str(res)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
Convert from what unit? km
To what unit? in
How many kilometers? 4.3
The result is 169291.430 inches.
```